# Adding success rate to each object in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, calculation

I have the following array:

```
 const array = [
{operation: 'buy', succeeded: true},
{operation: 'sell', succeeded: false},
{operation: 'buy', succeeded: true}, 
{operation: 'buy', succeeded: false}
]
```

I want to make a function which will check the success rate (succeeded: true = success, succeeded: false = no success) of each parameter and calculate percent of success (the success rate is individual for the objects that already been checked and not for the whole array)

expected output:

```
 const fixedArray = [
{operation: 'buy', succeeded: true, successRate: 100%},
{operation: 'sell', succeeded: false, successRate: 50%},
{operation: 'buy', succeeded: true, successRate: 66%}, 
{operation: 'buy', succeeded: false, successRate: 50%}
]
```

Comment: Please add more info. How are you calculating the success rate ?

Comment: On what basis is it supposed to do this?

Comment: it is mentioned in the comment. by true or false on each object @AyushKoshta

Comment: @BartKrakowski basis of the elements that's already have been checked

Comment: It's not clear what the specific issue is. Don't you just need to iterate the array and count the total number of buys and sells along with how many succeeded, and then math it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what research you have done and any attempts you have made based on that research. Note that Stack Overflow has many, many questions regarding calculating rates over arrays of objects.

Comment: @Nitai please check my solution when you have a chance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing we can't accomplish with a few simple array methods— `slice()`, `map()`, and `reduce()`

On my first attempt at this, I looked at the previous array item with each iteration like this: `array[index - 1]` but this wasn't as efficient, as it required more math to estimate how best to factor in each new percentage.

Instead, with each map iteration, I copied in all the existing object properties using the spread operator (`...e`), and then I added the `succeessRate` property. To calculate the `succeessRate`, I first took a shallow copy of the source array from the first item until the current item using `slice()`, added up all their `succeeded` property values, and then divided by the number of items.

This will produce the desired percentages, but in numeric decimal form, where ⅓ would read add **0.3333…** instead of **33%**.

To get the numbers into the desired format, still in our same `map()` method, we will multiply our numbers by `100` and then cut the decimals off using `Math.floor()`. Once that's done, we simply concatenate the percent symbol to the end of the number to make it a string in the desired format.

These were my steps to accomplish this:

1. Get array items from first item through the current item `slice(0,i+1)`
2. Map to only the `succeeded` property values `map(f => f.succeeded)`
3. Add the values (steps 1 & 2) `reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)`
4. Divide by the number of items `… / (i + 1)`
5. Multiply by 100 and cut off decimals `Math.floor(… * 100)`
6. Concatenate the percent symbol `… + "%"`

Here it is all put together and written as a reusable function:

```js
const array = [
  { operation: 'buy', succeeded: true },
  { operation: 'sell', succeeded: false },
  { operation: 'buy', succeeded: true },
  { operation: 'buy', succeeded: false }
];

const addSuccessRate = arr => arr.map((e,i) => ({ ...e, succeessRate: Math.floor(arr.slice(0,i+1).map(f => f.succeeded).reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0) / (i + 1) * 100) + "%"}));

const fixedArray = addSuccessRate(array);

console.log(fixedArray);

/* -> [
        { operation: "buy", succeeded: true, succeessRate: "100%" },
        { operation: "sell", succeeded: false, succeessRate: "50%" },
        { operation: "buy", succeeded: true, succeessRate: "66%" },
        { operation: "buy", succeeded: false, succeessRate: "50%" }
      ]
*/
```

Comment: @Nitai It also wouldn't be difficult to have the percentages in any other desired format— an integer without the percent sign (`33`), a float without the percent, but with the decimals (`33.333…`), the original decimal (`0.3333…`), or even a fraction (`1/3`)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you:
If you want to create a new property in an object you need to do as follow:

```
object.newPropertyName = newPropertyValue;
```

So to solve your problem you need to iterate the array and calculate the success rate
for each object in the array. Here is the solution:

```
var moneSuccess = 0, mone = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   mone++;
   if(array[i].succeeded) moneSuccess++;
   array[i].successRate = (moneSuccess / mone) * 100;
}
```

You can try the code here:

```js
 const array = [
{operation: 'buy', succeeded: true},
{operation: 'sell', succeeded: false},
{operation: 'buy', succeeded: true}, 
{operation: 'buy', succeeded: false}
];

var moneSuccess = 0, mone = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   mone++;
   if(array[i].succeeded) moneSuccess++;
   array[i].successRate = Math.floor((moneSuccess / mone) * 100);
}

console.log(array);
```

Comment: If you want to format the success rate differently you can absolutely do it. I made this that way to have the same results like you wrote.